# import 'swiper/css/pagination' this code in react and working with yarn dose not work for me

Tags: reactjs, pagination, yarnpkg, react-swiper

I'm writing a swiper pagination but i faced to this error:
'swiper/css/pagination' in 'C:\react\project1\src\Components\Testimonials'
and it does not show the pagination in browser

can someone help me to solve it?

`react`

```
enter code here

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'
import { Pagination } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
const Testimonial = () => {
    const clients = []
        {/* slider */}
        <Swiper 
            modules = {[Pagination]}
            slidesPerView = {1}
           Pagination = {{clickable: true}}
        >
            {clients.map((client, index) => {
                return(
                    <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                        <div className="testimonial">
                            <img src={client.img} alt="" />
                            <span>{client.review}</span>
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                )
            })}
        </Swiper>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I completed it.